# Wso2 mi dashboard create docker image

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am able to run my mi dashboard, (i'm using v4.0.1.17 as it allows me to replace the default H2 database), successfully on Windows. I now want to create a docker image for the same version, but I cannot find it's release in the official GitHub repositories. I tried vainly to build an image for provided version 4.0.1.2 and then replaced the zipped directory with my own 4.0.1.17 one, but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the updated docker image for MI Dashboard from the [WSO2 Private Docker registry](https://docker.wso2.com/). The page [wso2mi-dashboard](https://docker.wso2.com/tags.php?repo=wso2mi-dashboard) contains a list of all the docker images released with the update tag.

In your case to pull the `v4.0.1.17` you can use the following command,

```
docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2mi-dashboard:4.0.1.17
```

Note that you need to log in to `docker.wso2.com` with the WSO2 subscription credentials before pulling the image

```
docker login docker.wso2.com
```

Comment: I actually had tried this earlier, but I was unable to create a trial free-subscription account. Could you tell me which link I need to use to sign up?

Comment: You can use the same credentials you used when updating MI dashboard to v4.0.1.17.

Comment: I had used the same account creds I registered with then. I tried to sign up for a free evaluation trial with that acc, but I didn't get any confirmation emails..